# How to send large POST parameters with URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to create a class that allows me to send POST requests to a website whose content type is application / x-www-form-urlencoded.
The code I am using is as follows:

```
import Foundation

class HTTPClient {


 func getStringResponse(url: String, method: String, charset: String, parametros: [String: Any], headers: [String: Any])->String{
 var htmlCode = ""

 connectionRequest(url: url, method: method, charset: charset, parametros: parametros, headers: headers, callback: {
    (data, error) in
        htmlCode = data
 })

 while htmlCode == "" {

 }

 return htmlCode
 }


func connectionRequest(url: String, method: String, charset: String, parametros: [String: Any], headers: [String: Any],  callback: @escaping (String, String!) -> Void)
 {
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)

 request.httpMethod = method

 if method == Constantes.METHOD_POST
 {
     var postString = ""

     for parametro in parametros
     {
         if postString.isEmpty
         {
             var cadena = parametro.key
             cadena.append("=")
             cadena.append(parametro.value as! String)
             postString.append(cadena)
         }
         else
         {
             var cadena = "&"
             cadena.append(parametro.key)
             cadena.append("=")
             cadena.append(parametro.value as! String)
             postString.append(cadena)
         }
     }


    var httpHeaders = [String: String]()
    httpHeaders["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
    httpHeaders["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    for header in headers
    {
        httpHeaders[header.key] = header.value as! String
    }

    let encodeParameters: Data = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    let decodeParameters = String(data: encodeParameters, encoding: .utf8)

    request.allHTTPHeaderFields=httpHeaders
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

 }


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error  in
         if error == nil {
             let htmlCode = String(data: data!, encoding: .ascii)
             callback(htmlCode!, nil)
             return
         }
    }

 task.resume()
}
```

With this class if the parameter are simple, like "?name=One&surname=Two&city=City", this class works propertly. My problem is for large params. If I try to send next parameters it´s not working.

```
SAMLRequest=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%2BPHNhbWwyOklzc3VlciBGb3JtYXQ9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpuYW1laWQtZm9ybWF0OmVudGl0eSI%2BaHR0cDovL1MtUEVQUy5nb3YueHg8L3NhbWwyOklzc3Vlcj48U2lnbmF0dXJlIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwLzA5L3htbGRzaWcjIj4KPFNpZ25lZEluZm8%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%2BCiAgICA8U2lnbmF0dXJlVmFsdWU%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%2BT1U9IkFDIENvbXBvbmVudGVzIEluZm9ybVxDM1xBMXRpY29zIiwgTz1GTk1ULVJDTSwgQz1FUzwvWDUwOUlzc3Vlck5hbWU%2BPFg1MDlTZXJpYWxOdW1iZXI%2BNDE4MTk5ODkwODMwODMwMzQ4NjUyMjMxMzI3Mzg2MDM4MzYyMzM8L1g1MDlTZXJpYWxOdW1iZXI%2BPC9YNTA5SXNzdWVyU2VyaWFsPjwvWDUwOURhdGE%2BPC9LZXlJbmZvPjwvU2lnbmF0dXJlPjxzYW1sMnA6RXh0ZW5zaW9ucz48c3Rvcms6UXVhbGl0eUF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uQXNzdXJhbmNlTGV2ZWw%2BMjwvc3Rvcms6UXVhbGl0eUF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uQXNzdXJhbmNlTGV2ZWw%2BPHN0b3JrOnNwU2VjdG9yPkRFTU8tU1A8L3N0b3JrOnNwU2VjdG9yPjxzdG9yazpzcEluc3RpdHV0aW9uPkRFTU8tU1A8L3N0b3JrOnNwSW5zdGl0dXRpb24%2BPHN0b3JrOnNwQXBwbGljYXRpb24%2BcHNhMTwvc3Rvcms6c3BBcHBsaWNhdGlvbj48c3RvcmtwOmVJRFNlY3RvclNoYXJlPnRydWU8L3N0b3JrcDplSURTZWN0b3JTaGFyZT48c3RvcmtwOmVJRENyb3NzU2VjdG9yU2hhcmU%2BdHJ1ZTwvc3RvcmtwOmVJRENyb3NzU2VjdG9yU2hhcmU%2BPHN0b3JrcDplSURDcm9zc0JvcmRlclNoYXJlPnRydWU8L3N0b3JrcDplSURDcm9zc0JvcmRlclNoYXJlPjxzdG9ya3A6UmVxdWVzdGVkQXR0cmlidXRlcz48c3Rvcms6UmVxdWVzdGVkQXR0cmlidXRlIE5hbWU9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc3RvcmsuZ292LmV1LzEuMC9lSWRlbnRpZmllciIgaXNSZXF1aXJlZD0idHJ1ZSIgTmFtZUZvcm1hdD0iIi8%2BPHN0b3JrOlJlcXVlc3RlZEF0dHJpYnV0ZSBOYW1lPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnN0b3JrLmdvdi5ldS8xLjAvZ2l2ZW5OYW1lIiBpc1JlcXVpcmVkPSJ0cnVlIiBOYW1lRm9ybWF0PSIiLz48c3Rvcms6UmVxdWVzdGVkQXR0cmlidXRlIE5hbWU9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc3RvcmsuZ292LmV1LzEuMC9zdXJuYW1lIiBpc1JlcXVpcmVkPSJmYWxzZSIgTmFtZUZvcm1hdD0iIi8%2BPHN0b3JrOlJlcXVlc3RlZEF0dHJpYnV0ZSBOYW1lPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnN0b3JrLmdvdi5ldS8xLjAvaW5oZXJpdGVkRmFtaWx5TmFtZSIgaXNSZXF1aXJlZD0iZmFsc2UiIE5hbWVGb3JtYXQ9IiIvPjxzdG9yazpSZXF1ZXN0ZWRBdHRyaWJ1dGUgTmFtZT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5zdG9yay5nb3YuZXUvMS4wL2lzZG5pZSIgaXNSZXF1aXJlZD0iZmFsc2UiIE5hbWVGb3JtYXQ9IiIvPjxzdG9yazpSZXF1ZXN0ZWRBdHRyaWJ1dGUgTmFtZT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5zdG9yay5nb3YuZXUvMS4wL3JlZ2lzdGVyVHlwZSIgaXNSZXF1aXJlZD0idHJ1ZSIgTmFtZUZvcm1hdD0iIi8%2BPHN0b3JrOlJlcXVlc3RlZEF0dHJpYnV0ZSBOYW1lPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnN0b3JrLmdvdi5ldS8xLjAvY2l0aXplblFBQUxldmVsIiBpc1JlcXVpcmVkPSJ0cnVlIiBOYW1lRm9ybWF0PSIiLz48c3Rvcms6UmVxdWVzdGVkQXR0cmlidXRlIE5hbWU9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc3RvcmsuZ292LmV1LzEuMC9hZmlybWFSZXNwb25zZSIgaXNSZXF1aXJlZD0iZmFsc2UiIE5hbWVGb3JtYXQ9IiIvPjxzdG9yazpSZXF1ZXN0ZWRBdHRyaWJ1dGUgTmFtZT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5zdG9yay5nb3YuZXUvMS4wL25hdGlvbmFsaXR5Q29kZSIgaXNSZXF1aXJlZD0iZmFsc2UiIE5hbWVGb3JtYXQ9IiIvPjwvc3RvcmtwOlJlcXVlc3RlZEF0dHJpYnV0ZXM%2BPHN0b3JrcDpBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbkF0dHJpYnV0ZXM%2BPHN0b3JrcDpWSURQQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25BdHRyaWJ1dGVzPjxzdG9ya3A6U1BJbmZvcm1hdGlvbj48c3RvcmtwOlNQSUQ%2BREVNTy1TUDwvc3RvcmtwOlNQSUQ%2BPC9zdG9ya3A6U1BJbmZvcm1hdGlvbj48L3N0b3JrcDpWSURQQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25BdHRyaWJ1dGVzPjwvc3RvcmtwOkF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uQXR0cmlidXRlcz48L3NhbWwycDpFeHRlbnNpb25zPjwvc2FtbDJwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4%3D&forcedIdP=none&excludedIdPList=Stork&allowLegalPerson=true
```

In my code, the variable decodeParameters have not the same value than postString after do the encode and decode process. Exists any limitation on the length of this type of parameters?

[Edited]

postString variable have this value:

```
excludedIdPList=Stork&allowLegalPerson=true&SAMLRequest=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&forcedIdP=none
```

And decodeParameters have this value:

```
excludedIdPList=Stork&allowLegalPerson=true&SAMLRequest=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
```

Comment: It would help to show us what the string is when you decode it. I don't personally see anything wrong with your code, however you can definitely shorten it by using `let bodyString = parametros.map({ "\($0)=\($1)" }).joined(separator: "&")
            request.httpBody = bodyString.data(using: .utf8)`

Comment: "the variable decodeParameters have not the same value than postString after do the encode and decode process" How do you know? I don't see anything in your code that would check this.

Comment: I have edit my previous question to include the values of the variables. In my code I don´t compare the value of this variables, I compare those values on debuggin time.

Comment: I have finally resolved the error. The problem was not in this class, which works perfectly, the problem was that the parameter that was received was not properly scraped to use as a parameter. So I has created this function to encode the parameters:      func encodeParamenters(parametro: String) -> String {       
        let allowedCharacterSet = (CharacterSet(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] ").inverted)
        let escapedString = parametro.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet) ?? ""
        return escapedString
    }